# @capacitor/filesystem android 13 storage permission

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, filesystems, capacitor

I am working on an Ionic React app where I need to download a certificate image. Recently, we encountered a bug where the certificate is not downloading and gives an error. Upon investigating, we found that this issue only occurs in Android 13 (compileSdkVersion 33). It could possibly be related to permissions in Android 13. I have read many forums and blogs on this topic, but I haven’t found any feasible solutions yet.

Here is the code snippet

```
const base64Data = await base64FromPath(res.data);

        const savedFile = await Filesystem.writeFile({
          path: `Report_of_authenticity_${orderDetail.jobId}.png`,
          data: base64Data,
          directory: Directory.Cache,
        });

        console.log("saved file cert", savedFile);

        const albumName = "TEST";
        let albumIdentifier: any = "";
        if (isPlatform("ios")) {
          // Handle albums
          let albums = await Media.getAlbums();
          albumIdentifier =
            albums.albums.find((a) => a.name === albumName) || null;

          if (!albumIdentifier) {
            // Doesn't exist, create new album
            await Media.createAlbum({ name: albumName });
            albums = await Media.getAlbums();
            albumIdentifier = albums.albums.find(
              (a) => a.name === albumName
            );
          }
        }
        // else if (isPlatform("android")) {
        //   await Media.createAlbum({ name: albumName });
        // }
        console.log("cert albumIdentifier", albumIdentifier);
        Media.savePhoto({
          path: savedFile.uri,
          album: isPlatform("ios")
            ? albumIdentifier
            : {
                name: albumName,
              },
        })
          .then(() => {
            console.log("cert Image has been saved");
            present("File has been downloaded", TOAST_TIMER);
            setIsDownloadingCert(false);
          })
          .catch((e) => {
            console.error("cert error", e);
            present("Error downloading file", TOAST_TIMER);
            setIsDownloadingCert(false);
          });
```